# Selenium webdriver: IE 11 element.Click() doesnt work

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I tried to find any solution but nothing is not helped me.

I have this element

```
<span data-lkd="GUI-411396" data-lkta="tc" data-lkda="title" class="panelbar_item" title="Hledat">Form</span>
```

In Selenium I find it with

```
IWebElement form = GetElementAndWaitForEnabled(By.CssSelector("span[data-lkd=\'GUI-411396\']"));
```

It's not problem to this part. But if try click on this element in IE11 nothing happend

```
find.Click()
```

I tried some solution like:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
find.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
find.Click();
```

But nothing happend. In Chrome and Firefox is normaly click on element.
If I clik in other elements for example button it works on IE 11. But I need click on this element.

I'm using Selenium v2.46.0, IE 11 (x86, x64).

Comment: Please this answer could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171158/selenium-webdriver-ie-could-not-find-element

Answer (score 2):

With IE, it's always something extra you should do. Try this "special" trick:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", find)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to click on a span element. Instead of using a work around to click on the span element and trying to get the desired effect, try checking to see if it is wrapped in an anchor element or input / button element.

As an aside a good practice is to remember to always scroll the element into view, an example wrapper function would be:

```
public static void clickElementAsUser(WebDriver driver, By by)
{
    WebElement element;

    try
    {
        element = driver.findElement(by);
        scrollElementIntoView(driver, element);
        Thread.sleep(100); //Wait a moment for the element to be scrolled into view
        element.click();
    }
    catch(Exception e) //Could be broken into multicatch
    { 
        //Do Something
    }
}

public static void scrollElementIntoView(WebDriver driver, WebElement element)
{
    try
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

If you post a small code sample of what is aroudn the span I may be able to help further. Goodluck!

Comment: Instead of waiting for waiting for 100ms, Thread.sleep(100), it is a better practice to wait for an element to be visible, just my own personal preference. :-)

Comment: Very true, sleeping could result in over waiting or under waiting.