# Selenium Webdriver IE could not find element

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate to `www.google.com` and send some inputs to search box using Selenium webdriver with Internet Explorer(IE).

```
static WebDriver webDriver = null;
static DesiredCapabilities IEDesiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", TestConstants.chromeDriverFilePath);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", TestConstants.IEDriverFilePth);

IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
            true);
webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IEDesiredCapabilities);
//webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

webDriver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
webDriver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Venkatesh Kolisetty");
//webDriver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Venkatesh Kolisetty");
```

This piece of code runs very well when i use Chrome, but throws `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` when IE is used.

> This opens required web page in the IE browser which is opened by selenium. The problem is selenium is not able to find any element after page is loaded only when IE is used. For chrome, it finds required elements.

Is there any capability to be added in `IEDesiredCapabilities`

Kindly see the possibility of providing a programmatic solution instead of changing internet options manually.

Comment: the page may change itself when its opened in IE, Firefox or Chrome. So, you should inspect the page.

Comment: Provide sample HTML of the section you are trying to find and the way you are finding the element.

Comment: 'www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com' - No website is working in IE

Comment: locally hosted web applications are all working. Problem is with open internet websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after adding some required capabilities.

```
IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://www.google.com");
IEDesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
IEDesiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
//IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
```

`IEDesiredCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);` is optional

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is common issue when you use IE.

Open regedit.exe

Open HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones

So Zones will contain 0,1,2,3,4 and on right hand side three columns will be visible as soon as you click on 0 i.e. Name Type Data

Now in Name column look for 2500 Double click it. Put Value data as 3 and Base as Hexadecimal

You did this for 0.

Now repeat the same steps for 1,2,3,4..

Do this for all i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5 => Change all 2500's value data to 3.

After that run this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\CP-SAT\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

It will run on IE. You need a IEDriverServer.exe as i have shown in path, which will run your IE browser.

Reply to me for further query. I ran the above code in eclipse and it ran successfully.

Happy learning :-)

Comment: IE can open any page. Problem is selenium is not finding any element after page is opened only when IE is used. For chrome, this works without any issue

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, I'm able to open the page from above code and perform my actions. Can you please elaborate.?

Comment: i can see `2500` under 1 but not under 0,2,3,4. For 1, hexadecimal is set to value 3

Comment: I am using an enterprise version of windows in a corporate office. This is not for personal machines. kindly see the feasibility.

Comment: For me it is 0 to 4 and commonly everyone has. I also use corporate environment and enterprise version. 
Try Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center/Internet Option and uncheck Protected mode for all. 
You won't be allowed to do this but just check if it works for you.